# How to write a function that returns all the subsets with k elements from a given set in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

The problem says:

Write a function that returns all the subsets with k elements from a given set.

I managed to write a code to extract all the subsets from a set:

```
module Int = struct
  type t = int
  let compare = compare
end
module IS = Set.Make(Int)
module IIS = Set.Make(IS)
let addelement e ps = IIS.fold (fun s r -> IIS.add (IS.add e s) r) ps ps;;
let powset s = IS.fold addelement s (IIS.singleton IS.empty);;
let set = IS.of_list [1;2;3];;
let r = powset set;;
List.map IS.elements (IIS.elements r);;
```

Now the only thing that I have to do is to implement the condition so that every subset we get from the set needs to have exactly k elements. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily on the latest result you get by using `List.filter` , you could extract the elements that have a given number of elements.

```
 List.filter (fun x -> List.length x = k) (List.map ...);;
```

Comment: Ok I understand. But is there any way to implement it in the function directly?

Comment: ... hmm. there is a similar manner using IS.cardinal & IS.filter. One direction would be on powerset function that would compute recursively the powerset for k elements max...